# How to declare a variable type of list of JSON objects in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, list, typeerror

I am trying to do something like following:

```
  interface Iuser{
  addresses: JSON = [];
}
```

But it seems it doesn't work!

I want to store a list of nested JSON object inside the `addresses` like below:

```
[{
  "first_address": {
    "city": {
      "zip_code": ""
    }
}]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `addresses: { whatever the type of your address objects are }[]`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the addresses property should have its own type.

```
interface Iuser {
  addresses: Array<Address>;
}

interface Address {
  first_address: {
    city: {
      zipCode: string;
    }
  }
}
```